# Replace the GameObject when it touch the ground Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 prefab in my asset, one for the object when it falling to the ground and one for when it touch the ground, so i need a script that can check if the object with my first prefab touch the ground then replace it with my second prefab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basically what you can do is give what **"ground"** is in your scene a **tag** (let's call it "Ground").
2. To detect if it touches the ground you can do a **[raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)** or use the **[void OnCollisionEnter()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).**
3. You then **compare the tag** and if the tag is "Ground", you...
4. **Instantiate the second prefab** and set its **position to transform.position (first prefabs position)**
5. Then you **Destroy(this) ("this" is the first prefab).**

For example (Be warned: I haven't tested the script myself):

```
[SerializeField] GameObject object2Prefab;
GameObject object2;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {

        object2 = Instantiate(object2Prefab);
        object2.transform.position = transform.position; // Copies the Position 
        object2.transform.rotation = transform.rotation; // Copies the Rotation
        object2.transform.localScale = transform.localScale; // Copies the Scale

        Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

Or the Raycast version(Again, haven't tested it myself):

```
[SerializeField] GameObject object2Prefab;
GameObject object2;

void Update()
{  
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Grounded"))
        {
            object2 = Instantiate(object2Prefab);
            object2.transform.position = transform.position; // Copies the Position 
            object2.transform.rotation = transform.rotation; // Copies the Rotation
            object2.transform.localScale = transform.localScale; // Copies the Scale

            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Attach this script to the first prefab!

And attach your second prefab to the object2Prefab variable!

And also don't forget to put colliders!

Comment: Can you write for me the example script, thank you!

Comment: Can you write the script but using raycast??